# After the site loads it shows the contact section instead of the header

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I made it with react and anytime I reload the site it shows the contact section instead of the header first even after deploying it: [here is the link to the website](https://danielasakpa.netlify.app/)

```js
const Form = ({ emailSent, setEmailSent }) => {

  return (
    <Box component="form" ref={form} onSubmit={sendEmail} validate>
      <Grid container spacing={2}>
        <Grid item xs={12}>
          <TextField
            autoComplete="given-name"
            name="user_name"
            required
            fullWidth
            id="name"
            label="Name"
            autofocus
          />
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={12}>
          <TextField
            required
            fullWidth
            id="email"
            label="Email Address"
            name="user_email"
            autoComplete="email"
          />
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
      <Button
        type="submit"
        variant="outlined"
        sx={{ mt: 3, mb: 2, border: "1px solid #9F9F9F", color: "#9F9F9F" }}
      >
        send
      </Button>
    </Box>
  );
};

export default Form;
```

Comment: [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please provide appropriate code snippet. Not an direct link for others to debug. It's hard for others too.

Your issue is this line of code
in `Form.js`

```
        <Grid item xs={12}>
          <TextField
            autoComplete="given-name"
            name="user_name"
            required
            fullWidth
            id="name"
            label="Name"
            autoFocus // this is making it scroll to the input box
          />
```

`autoFocus` will bring the focus on that input automatically when page is loaded that's the reason your page is scrolled to contact section.